# variable in the MasterPage.master is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I got a menu which I have a condition either the user is log in or not to the site therefore some option are not showing up if the user is not log in to the site (option C).

Code from the MasterPage.master

```
<div id="menu"> 
   <ul id="menua"; class="ul menua">
      <li><a href="../pages/OptionA.aspx">Option A</a></li>
      <li><a href="../pages/OptionB.aspx">Option B</a></li>
      <% if(userIdAuthenticated) {  %>
            <li><a href="../pages/OptionC.aspx">Option C</a> </li>'
      <% } %> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

In the codebehing of the master page I just pass the bool Session variable to say if the user has been authorize or not.

Code from MasterPage.master.cs

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public bool userIdAuthenticated ;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool userIdAuthenticated = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["userIdAuthenticated"]);
    }
}
```

In the login page.cs  I just initalize the bool session variable to true if user has enter is credential properly.

```
bool buserIdAuthenticated = false;
bool result = pwdManager.IsPasswordMatch(txtMotPasse.Text, sqlReader["salt"].ToString(),  
     sqlReader["hash"].ToString());
if (result == true)
   {
       buserIdAuthenticated = true;
       Session["userIdAuthenticated"] = buserIdAuthenticated;
       Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
```

When I debug the code, everything is fine until I go back to the Master.master then the variable is back to false and I really don't understand from where it turn back to false because when I moved it from the Session variable it is set to true.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: is this the variable your are referring to bool userIdAuthenticated? Because you have 2 variables, one local to the Page_Load method and the other which is public in the class.

Comment: If I do this instead and remove the local variable                 public bool userIdAuthenticated = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["userIdAuthenticated"]);                    I got an error for the Session   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property "System.Web.Ui.UserControl.Session.Get                             Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Check my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the variable your are referring to bool userIdAuthenticated? 
Because you have 2 variables, one local to the Page_Load method and the other which is public in the class.
Think this is what you want to do instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   userIdAuthenticated = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["userIdAuthenticated"]);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I would appreciate if you mark this post as your answer to close this.